# How to treat NSArray of mixed content as of unified content?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Class B is derived from Class A.
Class B overrides '- (NSString *) description', overridden in Class A too.
I made a new 'NSArray' of pointers to instances, both Class A and Class B.

Is it possible to treat all of them in a cycle as Class A instances, more precisely - is it possible to use Class A '- (NSString *) description' for all of them?

Currently, I use a check if it's a Class B instance, and call initializer that makes Class A instance in that case. But it seems unnecessary, I don't like this solution.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Why do you want to do this? What's your larger goal?

Comment: I want to get a context description. Say, Class Worker derived from Class Person. If I gather Workers ask them "who are you, guys?", I expect them telling me what is their jobs. But, if I gather both Persons and Workers and ask the same question, I expect just the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example may be a little easier on the eyes than the solution in the other thread mentioned in Merlevede's answer.

```
for ( id item in array )
{
    if ( [item isMemberOfClass:[ClassA class]] )
    {
        NSLog( @"%@", item );
    }
    else
    {
        struct objc_super parent = { item, [item superclass] };
        NSLog( @"%@", objc_msgSendSuper( &parent, @selector(description) ) );
    }
}
```

The `objc_msgSendSuper` function can be used to call any method that returns an `id`

Edit - forgot to mention that you need to

```
#import <objc/message.h>
```

Edit 2 - based on feedback from OP in the comments, here is the ultimate solution

```
for ( id item in array )
{
    struct objc_super baseClass = { item, [ClassA class] };
    NSLog( @"%@", objc_msgSendSuper( &baseClass, @selector(description) ) );
}
```

Comment: That does solve it, but it won't work on the class, derived from B. If checks is necessary, then my "solution" (at the end of the question post) is more universal (creating a buffer Class A instance using initializer)

Comment: Ok, fixed it. Turns out the more universal solution is even less code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

```
for (ClassA item in myMixedArray)
    NSLog("@%", item.description);
```

This is valid if `myMixedArray` has elements of ClassA, ClassB. In fact (although not correct and very confusing) it works for any class or object pointer, even if they are unrelated to Class A or B. The only issue is making sure that `item` implements `description`, otherwise it will fail.

In your specific case it is very safe, because any element would somehow be a `ClassA` object (either directly or inherited).

If some day you need to have totally unrelated objects you can use `id` as the iterator type.

```
for (id item in myMixedArray)
    [id someMethodThatAllObjectsImplement];
```

EDIT (to clarify misunderstood question):
In Objective-C there's no easy way to force a call on the base class implementation, unlike C++, even type casting the pointer will prove useless. There's a tricky way to force calling the base class implementation explained on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865812/calling-base-class-functions-through-derived-pointers).

Comment: That doesn't work - in this case, for some reason, if it's instance of Class B, it will be called description: from Class B.

Comment: @explogeek Yes that is correct. What I meant by saying *any element would somehow be a ClassA object* was to clarify that using `ClassA` as the iterator object would be correct, but if the object is `ClassB` then it would call `ClassB`'s implementation.

Comment: but my question in topic was about ignoring that implementation - that's what I'm interested in.

Comment: The first part of it doesn't solve problem, and the second part indeed calls superclass method, but it won't work if I make Class C derived from Class B, and also requires additional checks. If checking is necessary, then my "solution" (at the end of the question topic) is better fitted, because it will work on any level of derive.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're solution would be nice. What you're trying to do defeats the purpose of inheritance. I think you should reconsider having a second property or method called `baseDescription` (or whatever) to force the invocation of the base class description.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds better, actually. Then I just call "baseDescription" for any derived class and it works. I just was curious, if I can do without it. If you will add that as an second answer, I'll give it a green V :)